# Forming URLstring conditionally

Tags: c#

i have 6-7 bool values like bookmark, authoredBy and some others as filters i want to form url such as if any filter applied it concatenate to the main url like 
something?bookmark=true&author=true and like this i can use if else but that will be lengthy are there any other approach

Answer (score 1):

Well, do this way ,

```
........
string url = "http://www.google.com?";    
if(bookmark)
{
  url+="bookmark=true&"
}
if(author)
{
  url+="author=true&"
}
...........
```

in the same way for other variables..

Comment: what if multiple filters are applied simultaneously

Comment: suppose along with bookmark author filter is also applied then the Querystring should like something?bookmark=true&author=true like this if all six filters are there then add all six values to query string

Comment: @Mac do that if condition for author also,like i did for bookmark.

Comment: that is what i am doing but the code becomes a bit lengthy so i was wondering if there r any other simple approach any ways thanks

Comment: @Mac Then use Dictionary<string,bool> and set the keys and iterate through it

Comment: @Mac, simple way is using ternary operators.

Comment: @Srinivas solution looks good, however, as @Pabuc has listed, putting the suffix "&" at the end is better.  If nothing after, no harm, but if her "bookmark" is not used, your URL will be  ..google.com&author=true and fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "google.com?";

bool bookmark = true, author=true;
if(bookmark)
{ 
   url += "bookmark=true&";
}
if(author)
{
   url = "author=true&"
}
url = url.Substring(0,url.length-1);
```

Comment: Srinivas's way wouldn't work if bookmark is false..The url would be google.com?&author=true which isn't right. You should add as a suffix not prefix. My way is the best way and won't fail ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [`URIBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.query.aspx) class. Check this example - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UrlBuilder.aspx

Alternatively, check the answer to this SO question. This is a more object oriented solution -

[ASP.NET: URI handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748609/asp-net-uri-handling)

Answer (score 0):

```
   string formQueryFromBool(string name , bool val){
         return ((val) ? name + "=" + val.toString() : "" );
   }   

 bool bookmark=false;
 bool author=true;
 var qString = formQueryFromBool("bookmark",bookmark) + "&" + formQueryFromBool("author",author)
```

Comment: I don't think that is what he means. He probably want to know how to receive it clean on the server side.

Comment: ya you are right filip what i want if any value is false then don't add it to querystring add only those which are true

Comment: @Mac & @Filip Ekberg & @Srinivas, i have upadated this before anyone comments, i think you have all posted when am updating my post........

Comment: @Srinivas, readability doesnt matter, OP wants to avoid lengthy if...else loop. Then this is the simple way...