# Encoding query string variables within Uri class

Tags: c#, .net, url, uri, urlencode

I have a **Uri** stored in a `System.Uri` class which contains a query string.

If I use `Uri.Query` the result is `?workarea=Airconaire+Ltd`

What I need is to be able to extract the Uri variables so that I can Urlencode `Airconaire+Ltd` to get `Airconaire%2bLtd`?  I realise that I could use regular expressions to parse this out - but is there not a more elegant way? Using `System.Uri` possibly?

**Edit:**

I've checked out the `HttpUtility.ParseQuery` class but it seems to decode Url encoded characters.  How can I preserve all characters (**theres meant to be a + in there**)  How can I prevent this?

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode? (System.Web)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get individual query parameters from Uri](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884551/get-individual-query-parameters-from-uri). Short answer: use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx).

Comment: Yep - but I can't Encode the whole ?workarea=Airconaire+Ltd just the Airconaire+Ltd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748609/asp-net-uri-handling

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a query string into a NameValueCollection in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624/how-to-parse-a-query-string-into-a-namevaluecollection-in-net)