# Path part gets overwritten when merging two URIs

Tags: c#, api, url, uri

I need to combine two URL's that both contain .Path information.

I would like to use `Uri` to give me possibility to .TryCreate(), so I can catch malformed URL's.

The problem that I'm facing is that the base [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) path seems to be ignored when I merge the absolute and the relative URI:

```
Uri absoluteUri= new Uri("http://hostname/path/", UriKind.Absolute);
Uri relativeUri = new Uri("/my subsite/my page.aspx?my=query", UriKind.Relative);
Uri resultUri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(absoluteUri, relativeUri, out resultUri))
      // handle errors
```

Output of the above is:

```
http://hostname/my%20subsite/my%20page.aspx?my=query
```

I would like it to be:

```
http://hostname/path/my%20subsite/my%20page.aspx?my=query
```

Is there a way to combine URLs that both contain path information using the `Uri` class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your relative URI should be relative, i.e., remove first slash (or add a period),

```
string relative = "/my subsite/my page.aspx?my=query";

Uri test1= new Uri(relative.Substring(1), UriKind.Relative); // without 'root'
Uri test2= new Uri("." + relative, UriKind.Relative);        // with 'current'
```

Working example:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://hostname/path/");
string relative = "/my subsite/my page.aspx?my=query";

Uri test1 = new Uri(baseUri, relative);              // original string
Uri test2 = new Uri(baseUri, relative.Substring(1)); // without 'root' character
Uri test3 = new Uri(baseUri, "." + relative);        // with 'current' character

Console.WriteLine(test1.OriginalString); // wrong
Console.WriteLine(test2.OriginalString); // right!
Console.WriteLine(test3.OriginalString); // right!
```

So, you probably should deal with your relative part like this:

```
if (relative.StartsWith("/"))
    relative = "." + relative;
```

Comment: did you try this? doesnt make any difference when i do.

Comment: @anders, yes, works for me; I edit my answer with a complete example; please, take a look

Comment: Ah i found what made your code work and not mine:
It seems that the absolute url must also end with / to make it work!
I used 
string absoluteUrl = "http://hostname/path";
and it didn't work, but with both end slahs after "path" and no start slash before "my" it seems to work! 
This seems flaky so ill test a bit more, but you deserve an answer for this one :-)

Answer (score 1):

It could be better to check both `baseUri` and `relativePath` when using [Uri.TryCreate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate):

```
var baseUri = absoluteUri.EndsWith('/') ? absoluteUri : absoluteUri + '/';
var relativeUri = relativePath.StartsWith('/') ? relativePath.Substring(1) : relativePath;
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58757870/5765982

> However, the base Uri has to end with `/` and the relative has to NOT begin with `/`; otherwise it will remove the trailing part of the base Url