# Path combine question

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Path.Combine for Urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls)

I have a root directory like http://localhost/

I have a file name call sample.jpg

when I use Path.Combine(root, file), I get something like http://localhost\sample.jpg, I am wondering if I can get http://localhost/sample.jpg.

Comment: Indeed, there are many implications when you combine url parts such as encoding, escaping, query string, virtual path being truncated. Should you need a more comprehensive solution, you can check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23399048/3481183

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Path.Combine` is designed for file system paths, not URLs, so I don't think it will give you what you desire in this case. You can always do the `Path.Combine`, followed by a `String.Replace("\", "/")` to correct your URL.