# Is there a URI equivalent of Path.PathSeparator in .NET?

Tags: .net, uri

I need to build up a URI path from string values and I'm combining them together.  Is there a URI constant for the `/` separator value as there is for `Path.PathSeparator`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls.

Comment: No, I know how to combine urls, I'm trying to avoid hard coding the '/' into my code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently there isn't. It's not platform-specific after all and [<strike>RFC 2396</strike>](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) specifies that the path separator in URIs is in fact `/`.

For combining URIs it's probably best to use the `Uri(baseUrl, relativeUrl)` constructor as suggested in Mike's comment.

Comment: I believe RFC 2396 has been obsoleted by [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)

Comment: there is some platform specific code in the [current implementation of the .NET framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs,3619), but that deals with special cases of the file:// protocol where there can be UNC paths... otherwise, there is the char literal `'/'` all over the place, so if they had defined a constant somewhere, they don't use it.