# Best way to join parts with a separator in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to join multple Url elements into one string, so I wrote the generic Join-Parts function:

```
filter Skip-Null { $_|?{ $_ } }

function Join-Parts
{
    param
    (
        $Parts = $null,
        $Separator = ''
    )

    [String]$s = ''
    $Parts | Skip-Null | ForEach-Object {
        $v = $_.ToString()
        if ($s -ne '')
        {
            if (-not ($s.EndsWith($Separator)))
            {
                if (-not ($v.StartsWith($Separator)))
                {
                    $s += $Separator
                }
                $s += $v
            }
            elseif ($v.StartsWith($Separator))
            {
                $s += $v.SubString($Separator.Length)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $s = $v
        }
    }
    $s
}

Join-Parts -Separator '/' -Parts 'http://mysite','sub/subsub','/one/two/three'
Join-Parts -Separator '/' -Parts 'http://mysite',$null,'one/two/three'
Join-Parts -Separator '/' -Parts 'http://mysite','','/one/two/three'
Join-Parts -Separator '/' -Parts 'http://mysite/','',$null,'/one/two/three'
Join-Parts 1,2,'',3,4
```

Which returns as expected:

```
http://mysite/sub/subsub/one/two/three
http://mysite/one/two/three
http://mysite/one/two/three
http://mysite/one/two/three
1234
```

I have the feeling that this is not the smartest approach. Any ideas on a better approach?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer by @sorens I changed the function into:

```
function Join-Parts
{
    param
    (
        $Parts = $null,
        $Separator = ''
    )

    ($Parts | ? { $_ } | % { ([string]$_).trim($Separator) } | ? { $_ } ) -join $Separator 
}
```

Comment: Have you considered a [URIBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on the answer from @mjolinor this one-liner passes all the tests in your question:

```
($parts | ? { $_ } | % { ([string]$_).trim('/') } | ? { $_ } ) -join '/'
```

If you do not really care about the last test case `(1,2,'',3,4)` and can assume all inputs are strings you can shorten that to:

```
($parts | ? { $_ } | % { $_.trim('/') } | ? { $_ } ) -join '/'
```

Note that I have *two* null/empty filters `(? { $_ } )` present: the first strips nulls or empty strings from the input, which rectifies your test case with an empty string `('http:/fdfdfddf','','aa/bb')`. The second is also necessary, catching input *reduced* to empty by the trim function.

If you really want to be fastidious about it, you should add one more trim to eliminate whitespace-only values since those are likely unwanted:

```
($parts | ? { $_ } | % { $_.trim('/').trim() } | ? { $_ } ) -join '/'
```

With this last one these test case inputs will also return `http://mysite/one/two`:

```
$parts = 'http://mysite',''     ,'one/two' # empty
$parts = 'http://mysite','     ','one/two' # whitespace
$parts = 'http://mysite','    /','one/two' # trailing virgule
$parts = 'http://mysite','/    ','one/two' # leading virgule
$parts = 'http://mysite','/   /','one/two' # double virgule
```

Comment: @SergevandenOever, now you have me wondering:-) you had accepted my answer months ago and now you have switched to a different answer also from months ago. And yet, mjolinar's answer passes only two of the five test cases in your question, while mine passes all five. Did I miss something ?

Comment: you are absolutely right! I was checking questions I didn't give an answer to on a small screen, overlooked I already accepted your answer! I switched it back! Sorry:-)

Comment: I downvoted this solution for one very important reason: READABILITY. This solution is very much unreadable to anyone without advanced PowerShell knowledge and thus should not be propagated.

Comment: Looks like in all cases the first  `? { $_ }` is redundant.

Comment: @roxton First thank you for noticing that PowerShell has evolved so that the first null/empty filter is no longer needed!! While I appreciate your enthusiasm to also suggest an edit, I rejected it because it lost some context -- someone reading the original post that still showed the filter would be scratching their head a bit as to how he got from here to there. That's why I think your clear, concise comment just above (that it is redundant) is better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example creating URLs using the UriBuilder class:

```
$builder = New-Object System.UriBuilder
$builder.Host = "www.myhost.com"
$builder.Path = ('folder', 'subfolder', 'page.aspx' -join '/')
$builder.Port = 8443
$builder.Scheme = 'https'
$builder.ToString()
```

Outputs:

```
https://www.myhost.com:8443/folder/subfolder/page.aspx
```

*Update* - here's a little function that should be able to combine your URL parts:

```
function Join-Parts {
    param ([string[]] $Parts, [string] $Seperator = '')
    $search = '(?<!:)' + [regex]::Escape($Seperator) + '+'  #Replace multiples except in front of a colon for URLs.
    $replace = $Seperator
    ($Parts | ? {$_ -and $_.Trim().Length}) -join $Seperator -replace $search, $replace
}

Join-Parts ('http://mysite','sub/subsub','/one/two/three') '/'
Join-Parts ('http://mysite',$null,'one/two/three') '/'
Join-Parts ('http://mysite','','/one/two/three') '/'
Join-Parts (1,2,'',3,4) ','
```

Outputs:

```
http://mysite/sub/subsub/one/two/three
http://mysite/one/two/three
http://mysite/one/two/three
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Didn't know about this class! Tried with System.Uri. Problem is still with Path for multiple parts. Need mjoliner his answer for that one! But thanks!

Comment: @SergevandenOever Yea System.Uri is the immutable version. You can get the System.Uri object from the builder by accessing the Uri property `$builder.Uri`.

Comment: @SergevandenOever I added a little function to my answer that should be able to combine your fragments.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the extra function. Looks a bit expensive though. The answer by @msorens looks much lighter, so I chose his answer. Thanks for all your great thinking on my problem!

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this:

```
($parts | foreach {$_.trim('/'))} -join '/'
```

Comment: I could not edit, but perfect answer. Must be: ($parts | foreach {$_.trim('/')})  -join '/'

Comment: Thanks.  I missed that brace.

Comment: But still not exactly: ('http:/fdfdfddf','','aa/bb' | ForEach-Object {$_.trim('/')}) -join '/' becomes http:/fdfdfddf//aa/bb, note the extra '/'

Comment: What does GIGO mean? :-) Ahhh... Garbage in, Garbage out... but that is exactly my problem:-) I have multiple parts comming from an xml configuration file.

Comment: I can understand having multiple parts.  None of your sample data indicate they were going to be as malformed as that mess.

Answer (score 6):

Drawing inspiration from the top answer at [Path.Combine for URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls)

```
function Combine-UriParts ($base, $path)
{
    return [Uri]::new([Uri]::new($base), $path).ToString()
}
```

Should be easy enough to extend to multiple parts

Answer (score 2):

Powershell has a `-join` operator.  for help type help [about_join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx)