# Path Combine of Url in Html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I built items  with image the `src` of image combine with path than in server and image name that in db .I need to combine them but  in the HTML .
This is my code

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ul_LeftMenu" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
 <ItemTemplate >
 <li class="li-LeftMenu">
 <img src="<%=Path %><%# Eval("Image") %>" /><a href="../<%# Eval("Url") %>"><%#Eval("Name") %></a></li>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

`<%=Path %>` from server Side

`<%# Eval("Image") %>` from database

How to make some think like this

```
 <img src=" Url.Combine(<%=Path %> ,<%# Eval("Image") %>)"/>
```

Server code

```
 public string Path { get; set; }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Path = "/Master/Images/";

}
```

Comment: You said: _`<%=Path %>` from server Side_.  Will this be a filesystem path?

Comment: Use what's already available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src='<%# new Uri(new Uri(Path), Eval("Image")).AbsoluteUri %>' />
```

Comment: This not alow me to insert <%# Eval("Image") %> or Eval("Image") this came from db

Comment: the src="" should be src='' otherwise the "" in the eval makes it think the string has finished

Answer (score 0):

If you have a base class for your controller, you could copy and paste the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399048/3481183) to be part of your base class.

Otherwise, you can copy the entire Uri class from [Codeplex](https://uricombine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#UriCombine/Uri.cs) to your project. That will extend the `System.Uri` with a new `Combine()` function