# Uri(Uri, String) constructor does not works properly?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a part of my code:

```
Uri branches = new Uri(@"https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/branches");
Uri testBranch = new Uri(branches, "test");
```

I expect `testBranches` will be `https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/branches/test`, but it is `https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/test`. I can not understand why Uri(Uri, string) constructor eats the last part of the path.

Comment: try `Uri branches = new Uri(@"https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/branches/");`

Comment: `Uri` is not a path, it does not work the same way as `Path.Combine`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1527643/284240 (see comments)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a slash after branches

```
  Uri branches = new Uri(@"https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/branches/");
  Uri testBranch = new Uri(branches, "test");
```

Comment: Adding a slash at the end of the first url also have no effect because  Uri(string) constructor removes it. And `branches` will be `https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/branches`

Comment: Sorry, I've found a probem in other part of the code. Adding a slash works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any official documentation for this (i.e., the trailing slash)? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

The Behaviour you see is correct, because replacing the last part is a good idea if you want to change the filename.

I would add the backslash at the end of the first part. Then it is clear that this is a directory, otherwise it may be interpretated as a file.

```
Uri branches = new Uri(@"https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/branches/");
Uri testBranch = new Uri(branches, "test");
Console.WriteLine(testBranch);
```

Will get this output:

```
 https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/branches/test
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behaviour.

If, in a browser, you were on a page with its full URI as `https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/branches`, and if, on that page, you clicked on a link that just had an href of `test`, you would be taken to `https://127.0.0.1:8443/svn/CXB1/Validation/test`. This is how a relative URI is composed with a base URI.

On the other hand, if the first URI ended with a `/` then it would work as you seem to have expected.

Comment: Is there any official documentation for this (i.e., that the URI should behave in this way)? I couldn't find any.

Comment: @RovinBhandari - yes, that second bullet seems to have it covered - you remove all characters to the right of the last `/` before appending the new text.