# concatenation of c#razor string with html string with trailing slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have `baseUrl = "http://localhost:10232";`

I'm using it in my view like the following:

```
<a href='@mynamespace.Controllers.MyVars.baseUrl/Tickets/Create'>Create New</a>
```

It gives me fine output i.e

```
<a href='http://localhost:10232/Tickets/Create'>Create New</a>
```

But if I add `/` at end of my url like `http://localhost:10232/`

Then is there a way to produce same result like above?  I tried it following way

```
<a href='@mynamespace.Controllers.MyVars.baseUrl+Tickets/Create'>Create New</a>
```

but concatenation does not work in html, so how can i achieve it (concat a c# variable with html string)

Comment: have you tried adding parentheses, like '@(mynamespace.Controllers.MyVars.baseUrl)Tickets/Create'?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls

Comment: @elolos. Right answer. thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wrap it in parenthesis and the static part in quotes:

```
<a href='@(mynamespace.Controllers.MyVars.baseUrl+"Tickets/Create")'>Create New</a>
          ^                                       ^              ^^
```

This tells Razor anything inside the `@()` is one statement, allowing you to put C# in to concatenate the string.

Or if your last part is *always* static, you can leave out the quotes and move the text outside the parenthesis:

```
<a href='@(mynamespace.Controllers.MyVars.baseUrl)Tickets/Create'>Create New</a>
```