# Middleware API between Angular and Web API

Tags: angular, proxy, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm evaluating the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework for implementating my project.

I have a requirement that consists of avoiding direct calls from Angular to API. This is because the API should not be exposed directly to the client and needs to pass through a proxy. If considering an MVC application for instance, I can create a proxy controller, like the one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145098/how-to-set-up-web-api-routing-for-a-proxy-controller).

For this scenario, is it possible to implement this with ASP.NET Boilerplate framework? If it is possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't like the idea of creating a proxy API service that implements all methods of the original one, yes! It's possible, you can do it with ASP.NET Boilerplate. I mean there's nothing special about calling a web API from ABP.

By the way, why don't you use an API Gateway? Something like https://tyk.io.

It has some cool features: rate limiting, securing, auth, monitoring etc...