# Extracting the Portion of the URL in C#

Tags: c#

I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/Catalog/Category/Detail 
http://www.example.com/Catalog/Products/12
```

Now, I want to extract the `/Catalog/Category/Detail` and `/Catalog/Products/12`   part so I can append with some other base url. How can I do that easily?

Comment: Have a look at the [URI class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: Have you put any effort into this yourself? A quick glance at the [Uri class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx), and use [`Uri.LocalPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath(v=vs.110).aspx) property like:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/Catalog/Category/Detail");
Console.WriteLine(uri.LocalPath); // /Catalog/Category/Detail
```

Comment: @johndoe And then to answer the question of how to append the `LocalPath` to the base, you can use an overload of the `Uri` constructor as answered in [Path.Combine for Urls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls).

Answer (score 0):

```
var segments = new Uri("http://www.example.com/Catalog/Category/Detail").Segments;
```

This will return

```
/
Catalog/
Category/
Detail
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Bloody negative voters... go read the guidelines... whilst I admit it only partially answers the question, how to get it easily, it does not show how to append stuff to it easily... it is nonetheless helpful and so does not deserve -1... +1 from me to cancel out the negativity.

Comment: @PaulZahra No, this returns the segments. But then what? How do you append them to the base path from there? Why would you ever bother doing this instead of using `Uri.LocalPath`?