# Path.Combine on urls gives exception : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, path, system.drawing, path-combine

I have an error in following code

```
Uri imagesrc = new Uri("http://somewebsite.com/demo/images/slideshow/29.jpg");
Image image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("/comph/", imagesrc.ToString()));
```

I have also tried following code - where `/comph/` is my root directory

```
Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("/comph/","http://some_other_website.com/demo/images/slideshow/29.jpg");
```

The above image URL is correct when I paste this URL in browser it shows the image.

With the above code an exception is raised:

> The given path's format is not supported.

What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: System.IO.Path is exclusively for file paths. What is your expected result? `/comph/http://...` isn't valid anyway.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: You cannot get a file like that, you first need to download the image (e.g. in a stream using a webclient).

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls

Comment: well the best answer was  @Krypto first need to download the image that helped me

Comment: You're still not clear about wanting a Path or a URL as outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Path.Combine` does not support urls.

You will have to translate the url to a (relative) file path first if you want to use `Path.Combine`

If you want to manipulate urls you can use [the Url constructor that takes a base url and a relative url and combines them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceyeze4f(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Please note base should not have anything after domain or must end with slash