# Why is my dynamic stylesheet url not working in MVC?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

This worked yesterday, and I must have changed something at some point, but the url path to the stylesheet no longer works with the following code:

```
@section Styles {
    @{
        string path = Url.Content("~") + Model.CssPath;
        <link href="path" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }
}
```

When I write out 'path' to the page, it's `//Content/site.css`. If I browse to `http://localhost:59278/Content/site.css`, it works. But, the link path is looking at `http://Content/site.css`.

Why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `href="@path"`?

Comment: @haim770 I thought so too, but it doesn't make a difference... if I look at the page's source, I still see  `<link href="//Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Be aware of the caching. This is also likely to result in another behavior.

Comment: @CSharper I cleared the browser cache (for always), still the same.

Comment: What is the value of `Model.CssPath`?

Comment: @JasonEvans `/Content/site.css`. So the `Url.Content("~")` really just outputs "/"

Comment: What if you change `Model.CssPath` to contain the value `site.css` only? What happens then? I think that having `/Content/` in the value is causing a problem. If you need `/Content/` in that string, then don't use `Url.Content`, simnply use `href="@Model.CssPath"`

Comment: @JasonEvans You're right. I just posted an answer. I don't know why the behaviour changed from yesterday, though. I'm 100% certain I included the `Url.Content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use:

```
Url.Content("~")
```

it gives you the root path of your site, *always ending in /*.

In this case, it is '/' as your local server doesn't have any subpath.  When you deploy to another server, it may be "/MySite/SubPath/etc/"  (still ending in '/').

As stated in the comments, `Model.CssPath` is "/Content/site.css"

So locally it is:

```
"/" + "/Content/site.css" = "//Content/site.css"
```

but when deployed, might be:

```
"/MySite/SubPath/etc/" + "/Content/site.css" = "/MySite/SubPath/etc//Content/site.css"
```

You can:

Simply change your `Model.CssPath` to a relative path (without leading '/') - ie "Content/site.css"

or

always use the equivalent of `System.IO.Path.Combine` when combining paths:

```
string path = new Uri(Url.Content("~"), Model.CssPath).ToString();
```

Comment: You nailed it. Running my code behaves entirely different when deployed to a server using more paths. After removing the leading '/', and including `Url.Content("~")`, it works flawlessly. However, using the Path.Combine method should eliminate the problem even with incorrect slashes. Thank you.

Comment: Worth reviewing the comments against [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls) as `new Uri` may not behave exactly like `Path.Combine`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

`<link href="@path" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Using `@path` tell the Razor viewengine parser to pick out the variable `path` from the Razor server-side code context, and dump it's value into the HTML markup.

EDIT:

Interesting. I have the following in a view:

```
@{
    string path = Url.Content("~") + "Site.css";
}

<link href="@path" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The renderd HTML looks like this:

`<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

I'm not sure how `//` is appearing in your url.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, it sounds like `Model.CssPath` contains `/Content/` which causes `Url.Content` to get into a mess, and that you simply need to just do:

`href="@Model.CssPath"`

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't resolve the domain in the url... the page's source still says: `<link href="//Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`