# Cascade a url string

Tags: c#, string

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls) question, i'm looking for a way to cascade a url like `Path.Combine` for file system does **including a path-parameter**.

My input are the following 3 parameters:

```
string host = "test.com"; //also possilbe: "test.com/"
string path = "/foo/"; //also possilbe: "foo", "/", "","/foo","foo/"
string file = "test.temp"; //also possilbe: "/test.temp"
```

The expected result is

`http://test.com/foo/test.temp`

This approach is the best I could find but it does'n work for all cases:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(new Uri("http://" + host +"/"+ path), file);
```

Comment: Why don't you trim host, path, file every time before you combine them. Then when you combine them use the forward slashes.

Comment: @singsuyash because `path` can be empty string

Comment: then trim based on case if forward slash is present, add forward slash if not empty and create a final host, path, file. Then combine them like scheme+host+path.

Comment: @fubo what about that extension method I used?

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes that's pretty good, i already upvoted Ales Potocnik Hahonina's answer before i asked this question but i'm looking more for a slim one liner

Comment: @fubo I think the idea of using the extension method for this task is very friendly and I think it is one of the best answers of that tread that it worth to be mentioned here too:)

Comment: @RezaAghaei i'm a friend of extension methods too but when you have too much of them and use them only once in your whole code, i better try to solve the problem without a extension instead of havin a overcrowded code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`Uri.TryCreate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Uri uri;
bool success = Uri.TryCreate(new Uri("http://" + host), path.Trim('/') + "/" + file.Trim('/'), out uri);
```

This will return `false` if the url is somehow in an incorrect format. However, if you are sure the format is correct, you can just use the `Uri` constructor:

```
var uri = new Uri(new Uri("http://" + host), path.Trim('/') + "/" + file.Trim('/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`UriBuilder` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) + `IO.Path.Combine` for the [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.path(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var builder = new UriBuilder();
builder.Host = host.Trim('/');
builder.Path = Path.Combine(path.Trim('/'), file.Trim('/'));
string result = builder.ToString();  // "http://test.com/foo/test.temp"
```

If you want the `Uri`-inctance just use the [`Uri`-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `UriBuilder`.

Comment: @fubo: then remove the redundant slashes. I've edited my answer and tested it with your samples.

Comment: exactly that's the part of `Path.Combine` i don't understand. it should remove or add them automatically

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
string url = string.Join("/", new[] { host, path, file }.Select(x => x.Trim('/'))
.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.