# Path.Combine not producing absolute paths

Tags: c#, .net, mono, file-access

I have some code running on Linux with Mono and I am trying to create paths which will then be passed to some file IO methods.

I'm finding that if I want to specify the root (eg: `/etc/blah` instead of `/MyApplication/etc/blah`) I have to do the following:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine("/etc", "blah"))
```

However as you can see I have to manually specify that the first part is an absolute path with the `/`. This defeats the purpose of the `Path.Combine`. I looked at the documentation for an overload to specify if it should be a relative or absolute path but there isn't one.

How do I correctly specify an absolute path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls

Comment: Do you always need to combine with /etc or any root directory?

Comment: As per the MSDN documentation, this is operating as designed. What comes out of `Path.Combine` is relative paths if you didn't specify that it's a root path, you have to specify that it's a root path. What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

`Path.Combine` is not designed to produce absolute paths. The path returned will be absolute if and only one of the arguments is absolute.

`Path.Combine` is designed to combine paths. It can combine two relative paths to make a new relative path. For instance:

```
string path = Path.Combine("foo", "bar");
// path is now "foo/bar", a relative path
```

In other words, the function behaves as designed and if you wish to produce an absolute path, provide an absolute path for the first argument.

Answer (score -1):

```
string rootPath = IsWindowsOS() ? "C:\" : "/";
string absolutePath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "etc", "blah");
```

Comment: Considering that Windows has potentially more drives than just one, hardcoding `C:\` is probably not terribly useful. Then there's also things like UNC paths ...