# How to go from String Interpolation syntax to String.Format?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, string-interpolation

I need to compile a project in Visual Studio 2012, so it wont understand String Interpolation..

What would be the equivalent to:

```
var uri = $"{BaseUrl}{collection.ToQueryUriString()}";
```

using String.Format?

Thank you,

Comment: `string.Format("{0}{1}", BaseUrl, collection.ToQueryUriString())`

Comment: @Rob make it an answer....

Comment: This does not answer the question but this should be of interest:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls

Answer (score 1):

As you said and Rob mentioned in the comment, [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) will be the answer, it will Converts the value of objects to strings based on the formats specified and inserts them into another string.The equivalent code can be return as :

```
var uri=String.Format("{0}{1}", BaseUrl, collection.ToQueryUriString());
```

[image]