# Path.Combine is adding slashes to file path?

Tags: c#

See the code below. I'm not sure why the two extra `//` are appearing before the file extension or how to best handle?

```
string avatarFilePath = "~/_images/avatar/";
string userId = 53da95a1-cc48-42d0-9a00-167f47ce5933";
string avatarFileExt = ".png";

string path = Path.Combine(avatarFilePath, userId, avatarFileExt);

//value of 'path' is: "~/_images/avatar/53da95a1-cc48-42d0-9a00-167f47ce5933\\.png" <-- note two slashes before extension
```

Comment: it's just displaying in the quick watch or in debugger

Comment: It's just escaping the string in the vizualizer.

Comment: `Path.Combine` combines Windows file paths, not URL or network paths. To combine network paths use [`new Uri`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path.Combine is not intended to create file names or build urls.  You should build the file name first, then use Uri to build your url.  Something like

```
string avatarFilePath = "~/_images/avatar/";
string userId = 53da95a1-cc48-42d0-9a00-167f47ce5933";
string avatarFileExt = ".png";
string fileName = String.Format("{0}{1}", userId, avatarFileExt);
Uri uri = new Uri(avatarFilePath, fileName);
string url = uri.ToString();
```

if you want a physical file path you could go with

```
Server.MapPath(url);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!