# C# - Uribuilder without parameter names

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've just started using .netcore.

I need to create a url, I've come across `UriBuilder` however I can only see example of using that with named paramters e.g.: `localhost?value=abc&another=def`, however I want to construct without parameter names, so:

`localhost/abc/def/`

Is this possible, I was thinking maybe something like the below:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = new Uri(_myUrl);
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;

var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
query[0] = "abc"
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: didn't get your question, can you explain with example?

Comment: that might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527643/517446

Comment: you can get by `request.RequestUri.Segments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how UriBuilder or URIs work. What you are trying to change/set is the [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.path?view=netcore-3.1) of the URI. That is done using the `Path` property, or using the relevant constructor of `UriBuilder`. Your example shows how to change/set the Query-String (key-value pairs, basically).

How you create the path is not the business of the UriBuilder class (see @Irdis comment about an option).

Basically, you can create your path manually using string manipulation of your choice, then assign it to the `Path` property, e.g.:

```
var b = new UriBuilder(...);
// Set other properties to your requirements
b.Path = "/the/path/ optional with spaces and other stuff/";
```

You can then use the `UriBuilder.Uri` property to get the full URI or use the `UriBuilder.ToString()` method to get the properly escaped URI. For the above example that would be something like:

```
http://localhost/the/path/%20optional%20with%20spaces%20and%20other%20stuff/
```